# How to translate Ajax validation messages od customer/account/create/

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-account

I have web store in Swedish and English language.
I want to translate password validation message like :

> Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than 8 symbols.
>   Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.
>
> Minimum of different classes of characters in password is 3. Classes
>   of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters.

How can I apply it? I have tried to add words in "**js-translation.json**" file in my theme folder but won't apply.

Comment: Which version of Magento 2.1 ?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.1.7